# Some information about the mapping of networks drive operation

Tags: networking, network-shares, shared-folders, network-drive

The server administrator of my company have created a directory structure on the web server as shown in this [tutorial](http://ideas.repec.org/t/serverintro.html) (but this is not very important for my question)

So, on the web server I have a directory structure like:

```
RePEc/

    aaa/
        aaaarch.rdf
        aaaseri.rdf
        journl/
            rdf files for articles 
        wpaper/
            rdf files for papers
```

After that the server administrator complete this operation I have a doubt about what is explained in this document: http://cdm-it.epfl.ch/dnn/Portals/0/Blogs_Files/Utilisateurs/Bureautique/REPEC/repec_tutorial.pdf

Please, go to the second page and here find the section **MAP NETWORK DRIVES**.

What is it telling me? In practice this operation is to create a new drive\folder that is "linked" to the previous directory created on the web server? (So I can operate with the file in these directories: creation, delete, modify)

Is it right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

A mapped network drive is to allow quick and easy access to a folder with the PC/Network/Server.

You can set permissions on these network drives to allow certain users to be able to modify/create/delete as you want to do in the above.

You've pretty much got it all covered in your post.